# how to regulate header of excel files with specific path in python

Tags: python, excel, spyder, openpyxl

I have 10 excel files in C:\User\lk. I want to regulate headers of these excel file. I wrote below code. But it does not work and there is no error. how can I handle it? (Colors, Font Size)

A example of data:

[image]

My code:

[image]

Comment: what is the problem or error traceback?

Comment: There is no error. But the process does not occur. And my question is that how can I handle it?

Comment: Do you save the files after making the change?

Comment: Yes, ı use wb_obj.save() method.